# Can I put a 25 gallon fish tank on an amazon basics desk?

Tags: safety

I have a desk from amazon, it says it holds up to 200lbs. Not sure what the tank weighs when full, I’m just wondering if y’all think it’ll hold the weight with some extra support in the center maybe?

[image]

Comment: This really isn't a woodworking question, but FWIW, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=25+gallons+*+water+density) spits out 208.6 lbs. for just the water, so you're probably really pushing it. I'd look for something sturdier.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Just as a general guideline for a query like this, you'd want to at least link to the desk in question. Nobody is going to want to go searching for the table on Amazon. *"with some extra support in the center maybe?"* If you're willing to add support underneath the middle then you've sort of provided your own answer. You can ensure the support *will* take the weight, making the weight-carrying capacity of the table basically irrelevant.

Comment: A gallon of Water weighs 8 pounds. If you do the math then you will know how much the water in the tank weighs, add the weight of the glass and the fish and the decorations. *Perhaps underneath your aquarium is not a safe place to keep your spare face*.

Comment: @AlaskaMan +1 for the face comment.

Answer (score 3):

With gravel and the glass , pretty close to 250 # . Not that much vertical stationary load : I would be concerned more with lateral movement . Significant lateral bracing is required. Some day someone may lean against it or someone may bump it. I see some diagonal bracing but I am not impressed. Full disclosure; I have built several stands , likely stronger than need be , and welded braces in commercial steel stands that I did not trust. I just started thinking , I doubt there are commercial 25's in the US, highly likely it is a 29 ( so 290 # all in). Some chance of a deep 20 . A 29 is 18" deep , a deep 20 is 16 " deep. Rough dimensions as my tanks in those sizes are stainless frame because they are old.

Comment: The diagonal bracing consists of metal straps.  These are good for tension, but will buckle in compression.  The only way these could be effective is if they were 'X' braces instead of just one diagonal.  In a 'X' configuration one piece will always be in tension preventing the other one from buckling.

Comment: The Bottom Line - That table should not be used as a base for your fish tank.